# How do you set up a Truffle script with Infura as provider?

Tags: web3js, truffle, infura

I'm trying to set up my Truffle scripts to use Infura as a provider.

I have the following, which appears to set everything up correctly:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");

module.exports = function(callback) {
    let Web3 = require('web3');
    const truffleContract = require('truffle-contract')
    let myContract = truffleContract(require('../build/contracts/myContract.json'));
    const provider = new HDWalletProvider(<my mnemonic>, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/" + <my infura project ID>)
    var web3 = new Web3(provider);
    myContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

    myContract.deployed().then(async function(contract_instance) {
            console.log("Calling contract...");
            response = await myContract.helloWorld({from: accounts[0]});
            console.log("Transaction receipt: ")
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
}
```

Except that it prints out "Calling contract..." and then never prints out the response. How can I get a better idea of what is going wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Infura will not keep your accounts unlocked as Ganache does, so it's probably not a very good idea to run Truffle tests on it.

Comment: I'm running a truffle script, not a test. I'm using the 'truffle exec' command.

Comment: Still, why should `myContract.helloWorld({from: accounts[0]})` work? You should sign this transaction with the private key of `accounts[0]`, and then send it as a signed transaction (in opposed to when working with Ganache, which does the signing for you).

Comment: It worked when I was using ganache and geth. The only thing I've changed since then is that I'm using Infura. Migration scripts are working without signing transactions manually. Truffle just does it for you, but I don't understand how and therefore can't debug when it doesn't work, hence his ticket.